Using a list-column as an input to the LHS of case_when
I am running into problems using a list column as an input to the LHS of dplyr::case_when().
library("dplyr")
library("tibble")
library("purrr")

# create a tibble and add a list column
tbl = tibble(a = c(1,2,3))
(b = list(c(1,7,8), c(1,7,8),c(1,2,3)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 7 8
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 7 8
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
tbl$b = b

I want a new column identifying whether each value in tbl$a is in the vector of values for the same observation in the list column tbl$b.
When I try this I get c(0,0,0), but I am expecting c(1,0,1).
tbl %>% mutate(a_in_b = case_when(a %in% b ~ 1,
                                  TRUE ~ 0))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>       a b         a_in_b
#>   <dbl> <list>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 <dbl [3]>      0
#> 2     2 <dbl [3]>      0
#> 3     3 <dbl [3]>      0

I'm not sure if this is relevant but these also give different results for reasons that are not clear to me:
tbl$a[1] %in% tbl$b[1] # evaluates as FALSE
tbl$a[1] %in% tbl$b[[1]] # evaluates as TRUE

I could use a map2()-approach, e.g.
map2(tbl$a, tbl$b, \(x,y) x %in% y) # this works

However, my real world data has multiple list columns and the map approach seems to become overly complicated.

I do not understand why you are expecting 1, 0, 1, since 1, 2, 3 are all in b: 1, 1, 1.

Thanks @Friede. The position in the vector is not important. If the value is present in the vector that is sufficient.

Use rowwise and then it is straight forward.
library(dplyr)

tbl %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(a_in_b = +(a %in% b)) %>%
  ungroup

giving
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      a b          a_in_b
  <dbl> <list>      <int>
1     1 <dbl [3]>       1
2     2 <dbl [3]>       0
3     3 <dbl [3]>       1


Not too sure what you are after. Base:
> Map(\(a, b) +(a %in% b), a, b)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 1

Note that
> Map(\(a, b) +(a == b), a, b)
[[1]]
[1] 1 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 0 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 0 1

while, for the particular case given
> Map(\(a, b) sum(+(a == b)), a, b)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 1


As you're loading purrr, you could use pmap():

These functions are variants of map() that iterate over multiple arguments simultaneously.

purrr::pmap(tbl, \(a, b) a %in% b)
# [[1]]
# [1] TRUE

# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE

# [[3]]
# [1] TRUE

To get the precise output format you're looking for:
tbl %>%
    mutate(
        a_in_b = unlist(pmap(., \(a, b) +(a %in% b)))
    )
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#       a b         a_in_b
#   <dbl> <list>     <int>
# 1     1 <dbl [3]>      1
# 2     2 <dbl [3]>      0
# 3     3 <dbl [3]>      1

This should generalise well to multiple columns. purrr::pmap() tends to be faster than dplyr::rowwise().

Using base R function mapply():
tbl |> mutate(a_in_b = mapply(\(x,y) sign(x %in% y), a, b))

#       a b         a_in_b
#   <dbl> <list>     <int>
# 1     1 <dbl [3]>      1
# 2     2 <dbl [3]>      0
# 3     3 <dbl [3]>      1


Take into account that the element position isn't important[1] and the necessity to manipulate multiple list-columns [2], here's two possible solutions:
# Toy data 
# Should produce b = 0 0 0, c = 0 0 0, d = 1 1 0 and e = 0 1 1
my_df <- tibble(
  a = c(1, 2, 3),
  b = list(c(10, 6, 4, 0, 3), c(6, 5, 0, 7, 4, 8), c(6, 10, 9)), 
  c = list(c(10, 3, 6, 8), c(10, 4), c(7, 9)), 
  d = list(c(3, 10, 8, 2, 1, 5, 7, 0, 4, 6), c(2, 5, 9, 1, 4),c(2, 6, 8, 7, 5, 10, 1, 9)),
  e = list(c(10, 8),c(0, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 10, 9, 8), c(0, 4, 10, 7, 3, 2)))

Take 1. mutate + across:
new_df_1 <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.list), 
      \(x_col) map2_int(x_col, a,\(xx, aa) has_element(xx, aa)),
      .names = "a_in_{.col}"))

Take2. pivot_longer + pivot_wider:
new_df2 <- my_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(where(is.list), names_to = "col") %>%
  
  mutate(a_in = map2_int(value, a, \(list, value) has_element(list, value))) %>% 
  
  pivot_wider(names_from = col,values_from = c(value, a_in)) %>% 
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with("value_"), \(x) str_remove(x, "value_"))

Output:
> new_df_1
# A tibble: 3 × 9
      a b         c         d          e          a_in_b a_in_c a_in_d a_in_e
  <dbl> <list>    <list>    <list>     <list>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1     1 <dbl [5]> <dbl [4]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [2]>       0      0      1      0
2     2 <dbl [6]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [5]>  <dbl [10]>      0      0      1      1
3     3 <dbl [3]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [8]>  <dbl [6]>       0      0      0      1

> new_df2
# A tibble: 3 × 9
      a b         c         d          e          a_in_b a_in_c a_in_d a_in_e
  <dbl> <list>    <list>    <list>     <list>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1     1 <dbl [5]> <dbl [4]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [2]>       0      0      1      0
2     2 <dbl [6]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [5]>  <dbl [10]>      0      0      1      1
3     3 <dbl [3]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [8]>  <dbl [6]>       0      0      0      1

[1]

Thanks @Friede. The position in the vector is not important. If the value is present in the vector that is sufficient. –

[2]

However, my real world data has multiple list columns and the map approach seems to become overly complicated.

